# Enabling coasting on a touchpad not recognised as such

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, scrolling, tablet-computer

I'm setting up a Linux (Devuan Beowulf) install for my Chuwi Hi10 Air tablet/hybrid PC. It's got a touchpad in the corresponding keyboard that's not a Synaptics but something else. Even MSWin doesn't have specific drivers for it; things like 2-finger scrolling and 2-finger-tap=right-click are done in the device itself.

It does do coasting under MSWin, but I'm not seeing any option in the Linux psmouse kmod to do this in software. Any idea under which of the settings below the feature could be hidden, and how to activate it? (I'd tinker but have no idea how):

```
> xinput list-props 13
Device 'HS-C109S-US-01-00- USB Keyboard Mouse':
        Device Enabled (172):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (174): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (307):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (308):       0
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (311):        0, 0, 1
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (312):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (313):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Button Scrolling Button (314): 2
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (315): 2
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (316):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (317):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (318):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (319):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Profiles Available (320):        1, 1
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled (321):   1, 0
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (322):   1, 0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (323):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (324):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (292):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (293):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (294):        0, 0
        Device Node (295):      "/dev/input/event8"
        Device Product ID (296):        7247, 99
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (309):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (310):       1
```

Answer (score 0):

It might work with the synaptics driver.

Install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` to enable it.

Comment: I see I didn't mention it but no, it's not a Synaptics and it's not recognised as one either by the Synaptics driver.